# Django Redirect treating view as a URL

Tags: django, url, redirect, view

For some reason, Redirect thinks my call to a view 'clients.views.teacher_profile' is a URL, putting it directly in the address bar as shown:

[Page Not Found Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkAI5.png)

How do I link it to the view and not treat it as a URL?

Note: I have altered some settings to accommodate django-allauth.

My code:

```
#views.py
def teacher_profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    context = {
        'user':user,
        'teacher':user.teacher,
    }
    return render(request, 'clients/teacher_profile.html', context)

def edit_profile(request):
    teacher = get_object_or_404(Teacher, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TeacherForm(request.POST, instance=teacher)
        if form.is_valid():
            teacher = form.save(commit=False)
            teacher.user = request.user
            teacher.save()
            return redirect('clients.views.teacher_profile', username=request.user.username)
    else:
        form = TeacherForm(instance=teacher)
    return render(request, 'clients/edit_profile.html', {'form':form})

#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^list/$', views.teacher_list, name='teacher_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$', views.teacher_profile, name='teacher_profile'),
    url(r'^accounts/settings/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the view's module path in the call to redirect; use the name which you explicitly defined in the url pattern.

```
return redirect('teacher_profile', username=request.user.username)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I did as you recommended but the following error occurred: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/settings/
Reverse for 'teacher_profile' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'username': 'test6'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Are you including that urls.py in a namespace from the main one?

Comment: Yes, I tried putting 'clients:teacher_profile' and it works now! Can't believe I missed that, still a beginner, you see. Thank you very much Daniel!